# How to move and copy multiple sheets into a single workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, copy, move

I'm trying to copy and groups of sheets to a new workbook using VBA.
But the number of sheets in a group can change depending on a criterion.

For example: 35100001-1, 35100001-2, 35100001-3 are sheet names in one workbook.

Now I want to copy sheets with sheet name having the character same these into a single workbook , so here I want a new excel workbook containing these sheets:

35100001 workbook

- 35100001-1 35100001-2 35100001-3 worksheets

35100002 workbook

- 35100002-1 35100002-2 35100002-3 worksheets

35100003 workbook

- 35100003-1 35100003-2 35100003-3 35100003-4 worksheets

35100004 workbook

- 35100004-1 35100004-2 worksheets

I'm trying to copy and groups of sheets to a new workbook using VBA.
But the number of sheets in a group can change depending on a criterion.

thanks for the help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Share the code you are using so we can advise on how to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete worked example.
Principle:

1. Work out the names of all the workbooks I will need
2. Create those workbooks
3. Step through every sheet in the workbook and copy to its new home
4. Save and close all the open workbooks

   Option Explicit

   Sub demo()

   ```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, colSheets As Collection, wbName As String
    Set colSheets = New Collection
    'First work out the names of other workbooks to create
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        wbName = Left(ws.Name, InStr(ws.Name, "-") - 1)
        On Error Resume Next 'force the loop to ignore duplicate keys
        colSheets.Add wbName, wbName
        On Error GoTo 0 'reset error handling
    Next

    'Now go create those workbooks - and save in same folder as current workbook
    Dim x As Variant, wb As Workbook
    For Each x In colSheets
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(1) 'forces the workbook to only have 1 sheet
        'Turn off warnings in case this is a re-run
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & x
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next

    'Now just copy each sheet to it's relevant new home
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        wbName = Left(ws.Name, InStr(ws.Name, "-") - 1) & ".xlsx"
        ws.Copy After:=Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(Workbooks(wbName).Sheets.Count)
    Next

    'Tidy up the new workbooks
    For Each x In colSheets
        Set wb = Workbooks(x & ".xlsx")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next
   ```

   End Sub

Plenty of room for improvement - e.g. error handling, skip any known sheets that you don't want to copy etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Export Groups of Sheets to New Workbooks

[image]

```vb
Sub ExportSheets()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DELIMITER As String = "-"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' In each 'key' of a dictionary, return a unique workbook name while
    ' adding each associated sheet name to a 'key' of another dictionary held
    ' in the associated 'item' of the initial dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sh As Object, DelPos As Long, wbName As String, shName As String
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        ' Prevent 'mayhem' if the only sheet of a group is hidden or very hidden
        ' i.e. very hidden sheets will never get copied but either won't
        ' raise an error if at least one of the sheets is visible.
        ' To simplify, exlude both.
        If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            shName = sh.Name
            DelPos = InStr(shName, DELIMITER)
            ' Prevent error if the sheet name starts with the delimiter.
            If DelPos > 1 Then
                wbName = Left(shName, DelPos - 1)
                If Not dict.Exists(wbName) Then
                    Set dict(wbName) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                End If
                dict(wbName)(shName) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Define the path: use the same path as the workbook (modify as required).
    
    Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = wb.Path
    
    ' Using the 'keys' (the workbook names) and the 'items'
    ' (the 1D arrays of sheet names ('keys')), export each group of sheets
    ' to a new workbook, then save and close the workbook.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim Key, FilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        wb.Sheets(dict(Key).Keys).Copy ' return the sheets in a new workbook
        With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count) ' reference this new workbook
            ' The following is all you need to save as a '.xlsx' file
            ' i.e. you don't need to specify the file extension.
            FilePath = wbPath & Application.PathSeparator & Key
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
                .SaveAs FilePath
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next Key
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Sheets exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide more details whether you want to have the process fully automatic or you want to run the macro manually for particular sheet names or how you put in the desired sheet name you are looking for, I made it quite simple. Provided code is a working sample. Kindly adjust it by your specific needs.

Method CopySheets asks you for base sheet name you are looking for (35100001, etc.) and maintains the whole process of copying worksheets.
It calls the method GetSheetsArray which searches for sheet names which met your criteria in current workbook and return them as `Variant array`.
Finally it creates new workbook where it will copy all relevant worksheets and saves the workbook in the same folder as current workbook. Name of the workbook is always identical with the sheet name you were looking for (35100001, etc.) .

```vb
Public Sub CopySheets()

  'Ask for the base sheet name you are looking for (35100001, etc.)
  Dim BaseSheetName As String
  BaseSheetName = InputBox(Prompt:="Base sheet name")
  
  'Array containing sheet names which fit your criteria.
  Dim SheetsArray As Variant
  SheetsArray = GetSheetsArray(BaseSheetName)  

  Dim wbNew As Workbook
  Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks.Add
  
  'Select and copy sheets.
  With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets(SheetsArray).Select
    .Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy After:=wbNew.Worksheets(1)
  End With
  
  'Delete the default sheet in newly created workbook. In case you have 3 default sheets, delete them in cycle.
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  wbNew.Worksheets(1).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  'Save new workbook in same directory as this workbook and give it a name
  'you were looking for. Adjust the saving path by your preferences.
  wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & BaseSheetName, _
               FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  wbNew.Close
End Sub
```

The Output array in following function is not really necessary and GetSheetsArray can be used directly. But I prefer to use it this way because if function name changes in the future, it needs to be modified only at one place, at the end of the function. It makes programmer's life easier.

```vb
Private Function GetSheetsArray(ByVal LookupName As String) As Variant

  'Basic initialization of output array.
  Dim Output As Variant
  ReDim Output(1)
  
  Dim i As Long: i = 0
  
  'Store all relevant sheet names in array.
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, LookupName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve Output(i)
      Output(i) = ws.Name
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next ws
  
  GetSheetsArray = Output
  Erase Output
End Function
```

If you want to search for worksheet names which met your criteria in workbook other then current workbok, you can easily modify the GetSheetsArray function by adding the reference to a workbook as an input parameter.

```vb
Private Function GetSheetsArray(ByVal LookupName As String, _
                                ByVal wb As Workbook) As Variant
```

Then within the function body you have to replace ThisWorkbook by wb.

```vb
  For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    '...
  Next ws
```